# @swc/jest produces non-class code even if target is set to 2021

Tags: jestjs, swc

My jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testMatch: ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.spec.js"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/test/"],
  // UUID uses esmodules so we need to convert it to commonjs
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!uuid)"],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$': ['@swc/jest', {
      jsc: {
        target: "es2021",
      },
    }],
  }
};
```

I am using nestjs and have a class that extends a class from nestjs:

```
import { BaseExceptionFilter } from "@nestjs/core";
export class AllExceptionsFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
   ...
}
```

And when I run jest it fails with:

```
    TypeError: Class constructor BaseExceptionFilter cannot be invoked without 'new'

      30 |     __extends(AllExceptionsFilter, _super);
      31 |     function AllExceptionsFilter() {
    > 32 |         return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
         |                                          ^
      33 |     }
      34 |     AllExceptionsFilter.prototype["catch"] = function (exception, host) {
      35 |         var httpAdapter = this.httpAdapterHost.httpAdapter;
```

Any idea how to solve this?

thanks!